# Not able to connect DynamoDB VPC endpoint from Lamba inside vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-vpc

Below error facing while accessing Dynamo DB via VPC gateway endpoint from Lambda function

Exception":"Resource temporarily unavailable","ExceptionDetails":"System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable\n ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11): Resource temporarily unavailable\n at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\n at Amazon.Runtime.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponse()\n at

Not sure what is the reason. I have ensured all basic AWS configuration for both Lambda and Dynamo Db and VPC endpoints.

Please let me know if anyone come across this issue

Comment: What does the policy on your DynamoDB VPC endpoint look like?

Comment: In addition to VPCe policy, also check security groups for both Lambda and VPCe.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html) and check the following things if they are in place:

1. check if the internet connectivity works for your lambda. Like the subnets in which your lambda is launched has proper routing setup for internet access
2. Check the security group attached to the lambda and make sure if they have outbound traffic allowed.
3. Check policy attached to the [endpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoints-for-dynamodb/) and routing is in place for it.

Answer (score -3):

You need to add Dynamo Db in the Same VPC to connect.

Comment: DynamoDB can't be placed in a VPC. It is always accessible publicly and you need a VPC endpoint to access it within a VPC, if Internet access is unavailable.